# why is my fitting with curve fit so sensitive to initial guess parameters

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, curve-fitting

I know, there are a lot of examples, where people try to fit cos with curve fit and it fails.

However, after reading a lot of these, I still have no clue, whats the matter with my script.

The data is relatively clear. My code does work sometimes but not reliably.

Here is my minimum example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos, pi, inf
from numpy import diag as ndiag
from numpy import sqrt as nsqrt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import find_peaks


def test(power, transmission):
    # function for p0
    def find_initial_guess(power, transmission):
        # find extrema for estimating initial guess
        # skip minor minima, which are just noise bumps
        minima, _ = find_peaks([-t for t in transmission], width=len(transmission) / 10)
        maxima, _ = find_peaks(transmission, width=len(transmission) / 10)

        # find neighbouring maxima and minima
        # select arbitrary maxima from the middle of the list ( so it is not just an edge case
        maximum = maxima[int(len(maxima) / 2)]
        minimum = min([maximum - m for m in minima])
        # distance of minimum and maximum can be used as initial guess for par2
        return [sum(transmission) / (len(transmission)),  # offset is average of transmission
                (max(transmission) - min(transmission)) / 2,  # amplitude is half the max-min-difference
                pi,  # phase offset
                pi / (abs(power[maximum] - power[minimum])),  # periodicity is 1 / distance(max-min)
                ]  #

    # fit function
    def thermo_optic_coupling(p_heater, offset, amplitude, par1, par2):
        return offset + amplitude * cos((par1 + par2 * p_heater))

    initial_guess_popt = find_initial_guess(power, transmission)

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(thermo_optic_coupling,
                           power,
                           transmission,
                           p0=initial_guess_popt,
                           bounds=[(-inf, 0, -6 * pi, -inf),
                                   (inf, inf, 6 * pi, inf)],
                           maxfev=5000
                           )
    popt = list(popt.tolist())
    print('fit          :', popt)
    print('cov          :', pcov)
    print('summed root mean square error', sum(nsqrt(ndiag(pcov))))

    fit = [thermo_optic_coupling(p_i, *popt) for p_i in power]
    initial_guess = [thermo_optic_coupling(p_i, *initial_guess_popt) for p_i in power]

    plt.plot(power, fit, color='orange', label='fit by scipy')
    plt.plot(power, initial_guess, color='red', label='initial guess')
    plt.plot(power, transmission, 'b+', label='experiment')
    plt.xlabel('heater power ∝ V²')
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylabel('transmission in mW')
    plt.show()


power1, transmission1 = [
    [0.0, 1.5625, 3.1250000000000004, 4.687500000000001, 6.25, 7.812500000000001, 9.375, 10.9375,
     12.500000000000002, 14.0625, 15.625, 17.187500000000004, 18.750000000000004, 20.3125,
     21.875000000000004, 23.4375, 25.0, 26.562500000000004, 28.125000000000004,
     29.687500000000004, 31.250000000000004, 32.81249999999999, 34.37500000000001, 35.9375, 37.5,
     39.0625, 40.625, 42.1875, 43.75, 45.3125, 46.87500000000001, 48.43749999999999,
     50.00000000000001, 51.5625, 53.125, 54.6875, 56.25, 57.8125, 59.375, 60.93749999999999,
     62.5, 64.0625, 65.62499999999999, 67.1875, 68.75000000000001, 70.31249999999999, 71.875,
     73.4375, 75.00000000000001, 76.5625, 78.125, 79.68749999999999, 81.25, 82.81250000000001,
     84.37500000000001, 85.9375, 87.50000000000001, 89.06249999999999, 90.62500000000001,
     92.1875, 93.75, 95.31249999999999, 96.875, 98.4375],
    [1.6562295294369114e-06, 1.814877400886339e-06, 1.9415786380553917e-06,
     2.032434337241163e-06, 2.07977581456966e-06, 2.0990197432469184e-06, 2.0990197432469184e-06,
     2.0512402206219947e-06, 2.0045482927134235e-06, 1.9328632951064806e-06,
     1.839538286344573e-06, 1.742643390948694e-06, 1.640984668617779e-06, 1.5322308981965023e-06,
     1.3777010363167424e-06, 1.2493325696095153e-06, 1.1189650542693485e-06,
     9.868258640760248e-07, 8.674581337360867e-07, 7.562624260369136e-07, 6.558233781566861e-07,
     5.746673504788186e-07, 4.927385300164335e-07, 4.2957559516582234e-07, 3.70524153320037e-07,
     3.5060372305501673e-07, 3.70524153320037e-07, 3.950456580084038e-07, 4.4306013694031485e-07,
     5.232635985089236e-07, 6.256551763793945e-07, 7.528015828064533e-07, 8.754201193092522e-07,
     1.033904733256672e-06, 1.1609580401117936e-06, 1.294566057151215e-06,
     1.4211237849175981e-06, 1.539030734443489e-06, 1.648589477558925e-06,
     1.7586133663896758e-06, 1.8561647616293735e-06, 1.9415786380553917e-06,
     2.0045482927134235e-06, 2.0702201126993254e-06, 2.0990197432469184e-06,
     2.07977581456966e-06, 2.0138008672355043e-06, 1.9415786380553917e-06, 1.814877400886339e-06,
     1.6871454442159815e-06, 1.539030734443489e-06, 1.3655054776415766e-06,
     1.1989926575358521e-06, 1.0195499872527435e-06, 8.363277813856736e-07,
     6.614627809764817e-07, 4.950220262917964e-07, 3.554811066871505e-07, 2.3324724541289197e-07,
     1.422237348203287e-07, 7.730111429536002e-08, 3.5477242527119533e-08,
     2.6814427162334455e-08, 4.768628023291028e-08]]
# the data is small, so multiply transmission by 1e6
test(power1, [t_i * 1e6 for t_i in transmission1])

power2, transmission2 = [
    [0.0, 1.5625, 3.1250000000000004, 4.687500000000001, 6.25, 7.812500000000001, 9.375, 10.9375, 12.500000000000002,
     14.0625, 15.625, 17.187500000000004, 18.750000000000004, 20.3125, 21.875000000000004, 23.4375, 25.0,
     26.562500000000004, 28.125000000000004, 29.687500000000004, 31.250000000000004, 32.81249999999999,
     34.37500000000001, 35.9375, 37.5, 39.0625, 40.625, 42.1875, 43.75, 45.3125, 46.87500000000001, 48.43749999999999,
     50.00000000000001, 51.5625, 53.125, 54.6875, 56.25, 57.8125, 59.375, 60.93749999999999, 62.5, 64.0625,
     65.62499999999999, 67.1875, 68.75000000000001, 70.31249999999999, 71.875, 73.4375, 75.00000000000001, 76.5625,
     78.125, 79.68749999999999, 81.25, 82.81250000000001, 84.37500000000001, 85.9375, 87.50000000000001,
     89.06249999999999, 90.62500000000001, 92.1875, 93.75, 95.31249999999999, 96.875, 98.4375],
    [1.396174174553104e-06, 1.2437906644035389e-06, 1.0933734492030595e-06, 9.231950062379674e-07,
     7.493565772474859e-07, 5.942121443423389e-07, 4.470013463798467e-07, 3.209402716365006e-07, 2.0673619727046636e-07,
     1.2646679820627658e-07, 6.225003507478826e-08, 2.7063535041190432e-08, 1.5904518423724243e-08,
     3.301448473686211e-08, 6.953709180130387e-08, 1.3921171470244173e-07, 2.3002252671138602e-07,
     3.5060372305501673e-07, 4.927385300164335e-07, 6.586370438602071e-07, 8.556507267350914e-07, 1.038734421672639e-06,
     1.2045269561883742e-06, 1.3295627259399386e-06, 1.4593866518595935e-06, 1.5741007416815629e-06,
     1.6793627797419938e-06, 1.7507193165159197e-06, 1.823060741632163e-06, 1.8983913848020828e-06,
     1.9155497976900293e-06, 1.8983913848020828e-06, 1.847832823818452e-06, 1.7665430107889611e-06,
     1.633414940040678e-06, 1.4920581674760974e-06, 1.3295627259399386e-06, 1.1717002525967601e-06,
     1.024312620215478e-06, 8.635043377359954e-07, 7.092257962431407e-07, 5.480251928284404e-07, 3.897772826233099e-07,
     2.6497879338257794e-07, 1.584588586826325e-07, 9.344973238413863e-08, 5.650105063022198e-08, 5.224160649199307e-08,
     7.561515230224364e-08, 1.2531196020926962e-07, 2.001284497590038e-07, 3.0707095931959394e-07,
     4.352970804255852e-07, 5.857557001760154e-07, 7.632319170881868e-07, 9.480514529881339e-07, 1.129318710440296e-06,
     1.3061280439519783e-06, 1.4593866518595935e-06, 1.6034836040919702e-06, 1.7186384491686294e-06,
     1.814877400886339e-06, 1.847832823818452e-06, 1.872941513580031e-06]]
# the data is small, so multiply transmission by 1e6
test(power2, [t_i * 1e6 for t_i in transmission2])

power3, transmission3 = [
    [0.0, 1.5625, 3.1250000000000004, 4.687500000000001, 6.25, 7.812500000000001, 9.375, 10.9375, 12.500000000000002,
     14.0625, 15.625, 17.187500000000004, 18.750000000000004, 20.3125, 21.875000000000004, 23.4375, 25.0,
     26.562500000000004, 28.125000000000004, 29.687500000000004, 31.250000000000004, 32.81249999999999,
     34.37500000000001, 35.9375, 37.5, 39.0625, 40.625, 42.1875, 43.75, 45.3125, 46.87500000000001, 48.43749999999999,
     50.00000000000001, 51.5625, 53.125, 54.6875, 56.25, 57.8125, 59.375, 60.93749999999999, 62.5, 64.0625,
     65.62499999999999, 67.1875, 68.75000000000001, 70.31249999999999, 71.875, 73.4375, 75.00000000000001, 76.5625,
     78.125, 79.68749999999999, 81.25, 82.81250000000001, 84.37500000000001, 85.9375, 87.50000000000001,
     89.06249999999999, 90.62500000000001, 92.1875, 93.75, 95.31249999999999, 96.875, 98.4375],
    [1.663904987577944e-06, 1.8312809813253925e-06, 1.959127394435598e-06, 2.0512402206219947e-06,
     2.089375623555793e-06, 2.0990197432469184e-06, 2.128220016564131e-06, 2.1087083781719565e-06,
     2.0512402206219947e-06, 2.0045482927134235e-06, 1.9155497976900293e-06, 1.7986207544535706e-06,
     1.6871454442159815e-06, 1.552721071155355e-06, 1.414844892100276e-06, 1.294566057151215e-06,
     1.1503143128228655e-06, 1.038734421672639e-06, 9.069871600668335e-07, 7.989811320185081e-07, 7.027494648298712e-07,
     6.203210568077912e-07, 5.330310688570652e-07, 4.7348784131211617e-07, 4.4502637870081293e-07,
     4.2580311206559627e-07, 4.2957559516582234e-07, 4.6311990409702625e-07, 4.905614836185237e-07,
     5.66489055218778e-07, 6.558233781566861e-07, 7.562624260369136e-07, 8.754201193092522e-07, 1.0148094985771049e-06,
     1.1556239224450914e-06, 1.2717482214298512e-06, 1.3777010363167424e-06, 1.4986797225052762e-06,
     1.6034836040919702e-06, 1.7266031287264504e-06, 1.814877400886339e-06, 1.9241870735205803e-06,
     1.9953382299096967e-06, 2.0702201126993254e-06, 2.0990197432469184e-06, 2.089375623555793e-06,
     2.041815627896478e-06, 1.959127394435598e-06, 1.8561647616293735e-06, 1.7266031287264504e-06,
     1.5813955906972397e-06, 1.4023702092175955e-06, 1.2493325696095153e-06, 1.0731798840385246e-06,
     8.832073557363544e-07, 7.124863091749079e-07, 5.355012926902759e-07, 3.791547695631538e-07, 2.5433475611234004e-07,
     1.5230712743292288e-07, 8.20050359899154e-08, 3.9698159260983884e-08, 2.744154275033995e-08,
     4.559654207832307e-08]]
# the data is small, so multiply transmission by 1e6
test(power3, [t_i * 1e6 for t_i in transmission3])
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can give more parameters to the fit, so it's less sensitive to the initial guess parameters?

why is scipy not able to adjust for the phase offset reliably?

Thanks in advance,
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's a good idea to normalize your data. Then, your bounds are very large. With your example, I fixed boundaries close to your 'guess' and increased the maxfex:

```
bounds=[(-10*initial_guess_popt[0], -10*initial_guess_popt[1], 0.75*initial_guess_popt[2], -10*initial_guess_popt[3]),
        (10*initial_guess_popt[0], 10*initial_guess_popt[1], 1.25*initial_guess_popt[2], 10*initial_guess_popt[3])],
maxfev=50000
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
As you can see, I used an initial guess. I figured, that the bounds are not so much a problem as much more the initial phase offset phi_0 is. So I just perform the fit 4 times for 0pi, pi/2, 1pi and 3pi/2 and select the best parameters with the lowest error.

Comment: Hey, so I tried a bit more and the bounds weren't to wide, but the problem is really the combination of periodic bounds and very small data. So normalizing in addition with multiple initial guesses helped a lot. Thanks for your answer :)